# Android.mk No rule to make target '*.c', needed by '*.o'. Stop

Tags: android, android-ndk, android.mk, ndk-build

I have some problem.

I use ndk-build but I can't make library *.so.

--------------------------------- Error ---------------------------------

```
nathaniel@Nathaniel-MSI /work/workspace/HealthCare $ ndk-build
 make: *** No rule to make target `jni/jni/src/filterData.c', needed by
 `obj/local/armeabi/objs/HealthCare/jni/src/filterData.o'.  Stop.
```

Under the my Android.mk source, help me please

--------------------------------- Android.mk ---------------------------------

```
LOCAL_PATH          := $(call my-dir)
SRCS                := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.c)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE        := HealthCare
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := $(SRCS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS        := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SRCS:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
```

**EDITED**

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/src
```

Comment: wow... thanks! so helpful to me, but how to guide my *.h?

my jni directory `Android.mk Application.mk inc src` and Enter the `$ ndk-build` command and then result
`[armeabi] Compile thumb  : HealthCare <= filterData.c`
`jni/src/filterData.c:3:24: fatal error: filterData.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`
`make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/HealthCare/src/filterData.o] Error 1`

Comment: It's easy. use LOCAL_C_INCLUDES.

Comment: It's the same as `$(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%,%,$(SRCS))` [GNU Make info](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)